# Adding Text Right On Javascript Slide Show

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to add some text right on a javascript slideshow, but somehow it doesn't work out. The text shows on the top and slideshow is looping below the text.

How can I make the text show right on images?  Please take a look

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="firstcar.gif"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="secondcar.gif"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="thirdcar.gif"
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100px; height:56px">
    <div style="width:100px; height:56px; z-index:2">Tring to add some text on the top
        <div style="width:100px; height:56px; z-index:1">
              <img src="firstcar.gif" name="slide" width="100" height="56" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
<!--

var step=1
function slideit(){
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
if (step<3)
step++
else
step=1
setTimeout("slideit()",1500)
}
slideit()
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify if you want the text to be above the image (not touching) or on top of the image?

Comment: What I meant is the text shows right on the images.

Answer (score 0):

you prob need position: absolute if you want to use z-index

or you can reduce the height of the img to smaller than the div container of the text

try this:

```
 <body>
 <div style="width:100px; height:56px">
 <div style="position:absolute; z-index:2">Tring to add some text on the top

</div>
 <div style="position: absolute;width:100px; height:56px; z-index:1">
          <img src="firstcar.gif" name="slide" width="100" height="56" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have used position: absolute for both z-index and reduce the size of the slideshow, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: do you have link to any css file? or style section in the head?

Answer (score 0):

Move the text you are adding into an element below the image element, give it absolute positioning, give the containing div relative positioning, and position the text using top, left, right, or bottom.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="firstcar.gif" name="slide" width="100" height="56" />
    <span>Added Text Here</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.container {
    position: relative;
}
span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Just a reminder, if this had answered the question, remember to "accept" the answer.